# How to achieve this logic function simply?

Tags: logic-gates

I need logic gate that behaves like this:

A=1, B=1, Y=1

A=0, B=0, Y=1

A=0, B=1, Y=1

A=1, B=0, Y=0

The tricky part is (A=1, B=0, Y=0) while (A=0, B=1, Y=1), AFAIK no logic gate distinquish between A or B inputs so dont think its possible with normal gate, is it possible at all?

Comment: You want a single logic gate that does this?

Comment: Is there a typo in the 2nd line? Why doesn't that line have a B?

Comment: Does this need to be a CMOS or TTL gate? Or would a gate in a different logic family be acceptable?

Comment: How many logic gates do you want to use? You won't achieve this with a single logic gate

Comment: nA + B is the minimum as far as I can tell.

Comment: Typo corrected.

If a single gate could this then of course, but I didnt expect it to exist. Whatever is the simplest way possible of achieving it.

Comment: For a practical solution you need to state what voltage levels you are working at and, preferably, what you are trying to achieve. If you can invert A , then it's just an AND gate but I'm unsure why you want a *real* solution

Comment: I dont have an answer for voltage levels or logic type as its only theory but why does that matter for answering this question? I can select the suitable logics chips myself , the logic itself should be the same regardless of voltages.
Assume any voltage or type.

If A would inverted ONLY in the case of (A=1, B=0) then yes that work, or more simply when (A=1, B=0, Y=0)... but I think that is pretty much the point of the question

Comment: @Jay, because some logic families (differential ECL, for example) don't require an extra gate to perform the NOT operation.

Comment: @Andyaka or \$\overline{A\overline{B}}\$ if you consider NAND to be a simpler gate than OR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the simplest way to achieve what you are looking for:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNU6iw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Edit:  As KingDuken points out in the comments, this is known as an [imply gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMPLY_gate).

Comment: Thanks @KingDuken I should have seen that right away.  Please see edits

Comment: Thank you, since my A signal was already going through an inverter this works perfectly, not only can it be done with 1 gate but the rest of the circuit is simpler too.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a *single* logic gate that provides the output you desire, there is no such thing. User @evildemonic has given you the appropriate solution for the most minimal logic gates you can have to achieve your output.

Here is a circuit with transistor logic that can be rather minimal, based on @evildemonic's answer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFlSER.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

At the end of the day, logic gates are made of these transistors (that behave like switches under the right conditions) so technically this is the most minimal you can design what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Practically it's not likely to be able to do this with a single gate (unless you're doing an ASIC design), but you could do it with a single chip, using a dual (or quad) NAND part:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0l39W.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>